# Strange behavior with & and | operators

Tags: python, boolean

Suppose type this into my python shell.

```
>>> print 0 != 1 and (1 == 1 or 2 == 2)
True
```

This returns the Boolean value `True`. Now let's suppose I change it up a little.

```
>>> print 0 != 1 & (1 == 1 | 2 == 2)
False
```

Now it returns `False`. Why?

Comment: [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're confusing `&` and `&&`. Note that in Python, `&&` is the keyword `and` (As far as I know, `&&` and `||` don't exist in Python).

`|` and `&` are binary AND and OR operators, which are really different from `and` and `or`.

Your second code is translated to:

```
0 != 1 & (1 == (1 | 2) == 2) # 1 | 2 is 3

      ↓↓

0 != 1 & (1 == 3 == 2)

      ↓↓

0 != 1 & int(False)

      ↓↓

0 != 1 & 0 # 1 & 0 is 0
```

Now, `0 != 0` is `False`.

Also please note the other answer about [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

`|` and `&` have higher priority than `!=` and `==`.